# what is the meaning of "!x" in "while(!x && i < n)"

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop

So I saw this in my text book and I cannot understand how it works.

```
x=0;
int i = 0;
int n;
while(!x && i < n){
    if(array[i]==target)
        x=1;
   else
        ++i;
}
```

what I don't understand is how "!x" works in loop's condition.

what I understand is this loop keeps running until it runs n times or when array[i]==target, which will change the value of x = 0 to x = 1 and stop the loop.

what I tried:
I tried replacing !x to x==0 and it did the same job.

Comment: You need to tag the correct language. But since this looks similar to C then `!x` and `x == 0` evaluate to the same thing

Comment: This looks possible only in C programming language. And this behavior is correct. In C, you can compare an int to zero in a conditional statement. If the code is like "if(!x)", it'll check for the value other than zero to execute this statement.

Comment: yes it is C and thanks for answering. First time using this so not familiar with it(forgot tag the language)

Comment: The purpose is to get around the programmer's ignorance of the `break` command

Answer (score 2):

The short answer here is that it does not matter what `!x` is because it is surrounded with [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Undefined_behavior) completely nullifying its effect.

In the statement

```
While(condition) {...}
```

`condition` must resolve to either `true` or `false`, and must therefore be logical expression.

Given:

```
int x=0;//This answer assumes 'int' here as not specified in OP
int i = 0;
int n;
while(!x && i <n)
```

Because `x` is initialized as `0`, equivalent to `false` the expression `!x` resolves to `true`, satisfying part of the condition.

Because `n` is not initialized however, the condition `(!x && i <n)` invokes undefined behavior, making the results of the overall `condition` unknown at the time of first entry, i.e.  it can be either `true` or `false`.  Further more, `n` does is never modified within `{...}`, so if the initial path happens to enter the brackets, the `condition` will change only due to changes in `i`.  But again, because the value of `n` is not known, only undefined behavior will occur.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language this is but `!someVar` is typically shorthand syntax for "variable is false", or another way of writing `someVar == false`. And in binary `0` is false and `1` is true. In the C language, `0` is false and anything not `0` is true. Therefore, in your loop, `while !x` is shorthand syntax for `while x == false` or `while x == 0`. Again,  generally speaking since we don't know the language.

Answer (score 0):

While(!x)  means if x is a condition then we go into the while loop, only if the condition does not satisfy.Here in your code you have assigned x as zero,so !x means 1 because '!' Basically means opposite if x =0 then !x =1, if x=1 then !x=0 (all numbers greater than 1 are also considered as 1 only) so while(1 && i<n) is what happening here in the next step.If i<n is true then you will enter into the loop. If i<n is false the you won't enter the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!x)
{
    intructions;
}
```

means that your instructions will only keep running over and over again if x is false or equals 0 and will stop executing instructions once x becomes true or different from 0